# Receive big list through TCP Sockets - Python

Tags: python, list, sockets, tcp

Which would be the best way to receive a big list through TCP Sockets ?

My code looks like this.
When u have to receive a big list, that doesn't work obviously.

```
    print 'connection from', client_address
    while True:
        try:
            data = pickle.loads(connection.recv(8192))
        except EOFError:
            print 'no more data from', client_address
            break
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? You're chunking your data by requesting 8192 bytes at a time, which is decent and probably the best you can do anyway. What improvements are you hoping to get?

Comment: Note that `pickle` is insecure - if you don't ***explicitly*** trust your source, `json.load` might be a better option

Comment: @AkshatMahajan It doesn't work for a really big list because i don't fetch string or items of the list but the list itself .

Comment: @WayneWerner I'll try this but it's not my main concern. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to transform the `socket` into a `file` object. You can do this with `connection.makefile()`. Then, instead of calling `pickle.loads()` -- which expects a complete byte string containing the entire pickled object -- call `pickle.load(connection.makefile())`. This way, you let the `pickle` module handle reading the entire "file". It will call the object's `read` function repeatedly until it has received all the expected data.

That basically assumes that the entire remaining part of the stream is to be unpickled (which appears to be what you're trying to do so it sounds like it should work). Otherwise, you may need to wrap your own pseudo-file-object around the stream that has some independent knowledge of the end of the pickled object.

Comment: That's awesome !! Thank you :)